# Unable to find the Null space of a matrix R

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

```
R = {{-639880.9531714534` + 
     79.19371296239888` c^2, -453339.5840789839` + 
     55.56821108386519` c^2, 0, 0, 
    160.0595864532318`}, {-453339.5840789839` + 
     55.56821108386519` c^2, -4.986933805092816`*^6 + 
     74.24759881256949` c^2, 0, 0, -0.00447586740976628`}, {0, 
    0, -639877.8131714534` + 
     79.19371296239888` c^2, -453339.5840789839` + 
     55.56821108386519` c^2, 160.0595864532318`}, {0, 
    0, -453339.5840789839` + 
     55.56821108386519` c^2, -4.986933805092816`*^6 + 
     74.24759881256949` c^2, -0.00447586740976628`}, \
{160.0595864532318`, -0.00447586740976628`, 
    160.0595864532318`, -0.00447586740976628`, -520.8333333333335`}};
MatrixRank[R]
P = FullSimplify[Det[R]]
s1 = NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < c < 10000]
s2 = Flatten[c /. s1]
NN = Flatten[NullSpace[R /. c -> s2[[1]]]];
```

I have a matrix R which is having a dependency on `c`. I took the `Det[R]` and found the Roots of the **determinant function**. I substituted the back to find the unknown coefficients. Essentially I am talking about  `Ax=0`, But could not able to find the `x`

Comment: There is noise in that code. Please provide a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example). What is `s3`? Why do you define `fn`?

Comment: NullSpace[R] gives an empty list. Why do you say you can't find the NullSpace ?

Comment: Can Nullspace be nonempty, Even we can able to find the Root of a determinant function?

Comment: Computing the determinant to check wether a matrix is invertible is (i) highly inefficient and (ii) extremely inaccurate as a _lot_ of numerical error can be accumulated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a problem of not having enough digits in the default machine precision. After running your original code, try

```
P /. s1
(*not zeroes*)
```

The fact that, after replacing the solution into the equation, one does not get something close to zero is the hint.

One way to force Mathematica to use more digits is as follows:

```
newR = ReplaceAll[R, x_?NumericQ :> Rationalize[x, 1/100000000000000]];
newS = NSolve[Det[newR] == 0 && 0 < c < 10000, WorkingPrecision -> 60];
Flatten[NullSpace[newR /. newS[[1]]]]
(*1D nullspace*)
```

Comment: Thanks, I Implemented your suggestion and its working now.

Answer (score 3):

The presence of machine numbers and use of `Det` means there will be some amount of numerical error which in turn means one cannot necessarily get away with the default `Tolerance` for `NullSpace`. Dropping it somewhat does give a nontrivial null space generator.

```
NullSpace[R /. c -> s2[[1]], Tolerance -> 10^(-10)]

(* Out[62]= {{0.638092335503, -0.000643559092341, 
  0.658783883462, -0.000664427898733, 0.398548755651}} *)
```

This is not terribly good though (and I am not sure why). Instead I will recommend using the singular values decomposition. The

```
{uu, ww, vv} = SingularValueDecomposition[R /. c -> s2[[2]]];
nullvec = Last[Transpose[vv]]

(* Out[84]= {0.718279572307, -0.000713124517697, -0.695719341907, \
0.000690726186956, 0.00693308400591} *)

Check:

(R /. c -> s2[[2]]).Last[Transpose[vv]]

(* Out[85]= {-4.82763022225*10^-7, 6.63228964986*10^-10, 
 4.6759873662*10^-7, -4.65453959914*10^-10, -4.65985650067*10^-9} *)
```